# Treat thrip on houseplants

Tags: indoors, pests, pest-control, pesticide

I diagnosed these little guys as [thrips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips) as you could see them and the typical silvery trails in the leaves where the immature thrip live.  They had spread to the ivy and philodendron plants inside the house.

I cut the plants back and put them outside as that works well in controlling many household pests but they are back on the new growth.

Any suggestions on controlling them?  Pesticides for homeowners are restricted where I live so I can buy soap and permethrin products.  I cannot buy Neem oil or systemics.

Any suggestions for a treatment plan for thrips on indoor plants?

[image: thrip on a leaf]